# How to make Google Slide update value WITHOUT having to manually open it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have a Google Sheet with a Google Apps Script that basically intends to do the following when triggered:

1. Open a specific Google Slides file (it's a template)
2. Duplicate it into a specific subfolder
3. Change some placeholder values of this copy
4. Send this new Google Slide via Email as a PDF.

Everything works great EXCEPT for step 3, which for some reason ONLY updates when I manually open this new file. So the PDF that I receive via email actually still contains the placeholder values, as does the "preview" I see on my Drive before opening the Slides presentation. However, if I open it, it automatically shows the new updated values. I can't figure out why this might be happening.

Things I tried:

1. Add `Utilities.sleep()` to allow for the values to update, but it doesn't seem to work. Only opening it does it.
2. Add a line to `.openById()` again in case this "forces it to open", but doesn't work.
3. Adding a loop to refresh each slide.

This is a minimal reproducible code that I have, but would require a Google Slide with two placeholders as `"[var_0]"` and `"[var_1]"`:

```
const idTemplate = "1BugZRdW8aOzgPOZun-j_U60lC-yXQFXug3R2-MR7AFs";

function generatePresentationData() {
  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //Data is in A2:B2 of "Records" sheet.
  var ss = s.getSheetByName("Records");
  var data = ss.getRange("A2:B2").getValues();

  //Get the Google Slides template
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(idTemplate);

  //Create a copy of the template into a specific folder, and get the ID of this copy
  var newParte = file.makeCopy("New Parte", DriveApp.getFolderById("1rCEYVilGiOlxh03aFANzD4qgKXKBmODh"));
  var newParteId = newParte.getId();

  //Get the slides of this file.
  var slides = getSlides_(newParteId);

  //Replace the placeholders with the value in A2:B2. This is the part that doesn't actually "shows up" on this new file until I manually open it from my Drive. It does work correctly, so I don't think the issue lies here
  writeDataToPlayersSlide_(slides, data);

  //I have tried adding a wait period but didn't work
  Utilities.sleep(60000);

  //I also tried defining the file again before proceeding to send it via email, but again didn't work
  var newParte = DriveApp.getFileById(newParteId);

  //I also tried refreshing each slide
  refreshSlides(SlidesApp.openById(newParteId));
  
  //Get this new file as a Blob
  var theBlob = newParte.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  
  var nameFile = 'Test.pdf';
  var email = "mail@gmail.com";
  var subject = 'Test Subject';
  var body = 'Hi!, <br/>Here is your file.';
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    htmlBody: body,
    attachments: [{
      fileName: nameFile,
      content: theBlob.getBytes(),
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
      }]
   });

}

function getSlides_(newParteId){
  let presentation = SlidesApp.openById(newParteId);
  let slides = presentation.getSlides();
  return slides;
}

function writeDataToPlayersSlide_(slides, data){
  let parte = slides[0];
  for (let index=0;index<data[0].length;index++){
    parte.replaceAllText(`[var_${index}]`,data[0][index]);
  }
}

function refreshSlides(presentation){
 
  // loop through all slides and refresh them
  numSlides = presentation.getSlides().length;
  for (i = 0; i < numSlides; i++) {
    presentation.getSlides()[i].refreshSlide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Without looking through all of your code, wouldn't `getActiveSpreadsheet()` not work if being called from email? Have you tried your code with the actual spreadsheet ID as you did with your slides file?

Comment: I will definitely keep this in mind for the future, but right now I'm in a phase where I'm testing it by running it directly from the Spreadsheet, so it does work. The problem lies in the Google Slide not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
  //I have tried adding a wait period but didn't work
  Utilities.sleep(60000);

  //I also tried defining the file again before proceeding to send it via email, but again didn't work
  var newParte = DriveApp.getFileById(newParteId);

  //I also tried refreshing each slide
  refreshSlides(SlidesApp.openById(newParteId));
```

use

```
newParte.saveAndClose();
newParte = DriveApp.getFileById(newParteId);
```

---

Apparently the problem is that you have missed that Google Apps Script applies changes to Docs Editors files after the script ends.

If order to force Google Apps Script applies the changes at some point, i.e before sendding an email, when making changes to

- spreadsheets use [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)
- documents use [`DocumentsApp.Document.saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)
- presentations use [`SlidesApp.Presentation.saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose)

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually used:
`SlidesApp.openById(newParteId).saveAndClose();`
but this was basically what I was looking for.